# Form_for with model name different to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `Person`, and I want to have a resource called `Employee`. I found that this will stop the `form_for` magic.

I need to pass in the `@person` object itself so form_for can choose the correct action path (create or update).

However this will mean that form_for uses `POST people_path` and `PUT person_path` in the output, instead of `employee_path`s.

Is it possible to have all the Rails convention goodies while my model and controller have different names?

Comment: Do you use your People model in multiple contexts? I mean, do you have any other resources based on this model? BTW 'People' is a terrible name for a model - model names should be singular.

Comment: Yeah it is used in multiple context. And my mistake, Person should be the correct name for the model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use "employees" in routes/url you can use "path" in routes
eg.
create controller as people_controller but in routes

```
resources :people, path: "employees"
```

so routes will be like

```
new_person GET    /employees/new
people GET    /employees
```

etc

So following will work

```
<%= form_for @people do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Note: For this You have to use Person model

Answer (score 6):

you can add a option: url: employee_path

e.g.

```
<%= form_for @people, :as => :post, :url => employee_path(@people) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes, but this means I have to handle 'update' case as well manually. I am looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not OP, but I prefer your solution. How could that be used for a `new` action? I'm currently trying with `form_for @people, url: employee_path, html: {method: :post} do |f|` and I get an error that I'm missing the id, but it is sending me to the show action instead of create.

Comment: @user3209270, `url: employees_path` is for create

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to say `employees_path`. I'm using different models but very similar to OP's, in my case `news` is the equivalent of `employees`, and `article` for `person`. I'm using `form_for @article, url: news_path, html: {method: :post} do |f|` and the full error I get is `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news"} missing required keys: [:id]`.

Comment: I think I screwed up something. I made another controller (to avoid the `new` and `news` confusion) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

So I've got a custom C.R.M. that I've built, and it uses employees_controller to pass and retrieve values from Devise's User model. I didn't want Devise views to be accessible, but I wanted to use Devise for user authentication since... let's face it, they've got that figured out pretty darn well.

Well, as it turns out, I was having some trouble with this same issue, I had an embedded Ruby tag for the form:

```
<%= form_for @employee, as: :user, url: employees_path do |f| %>
```

The problem here should be obvious (though it took me a good hour to find) - if I'm on the "new" action, it'll work great. It'll take the form data, pass that into a new User.new object, and create a new user for me. But, if I'm trying to *edit* my employee's information, say by updating their password or by adding some more to their description, it'll fail - saying there is no "[PATCH] method for path /employees", which is true.

A little hacky I suppose, but my solution was simply to put an @path instance variable in the "new" and "edit" actions:

```
def new
  @path = employees_path
end

def edit
  @path = employee_path
end
```

I tested it, and it works great. If anyone has any critique to this method, by all means - I'd love to hear it.

My environment:

- Rails 5.2.0
- Devise 4.4.3